# Ansible: Run cron at different hours per host

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, ansible

I have the need to configure a cron job to run at different hours on multiple hosts.
Ideally I would like to have an index that identifies the host I am currently modifying and offset it.

So if I run ansible against:

```
HOSTA
HOSTB
HOSTC
```

I want to configure cron to be like this

```
0 1 * * * #HOSTA
0 2 * * * #HOSTB
0 3 * * * #HOSTC
```

Do you know how I can achieve it without hardcoding a variable per host?

Comment: Is it necessary to have exactly one hour between the runs on each host? You could use, e.g., bits from their IP addresses to add some change to the job (let us say you take the last octet and divide it by four).

Comment: I thought of that but I want it to be kind of deterministic rather than relying on ip addresses which might change.

Answer (score 4):

You can use loop with_items over a array of dictionaries. Then filter appropriate items using inventory_hostname or ansible_hostname:

```
- name: cron jobs
  cron: min=0 hour={{ item.h }} job="echo server {{ item.s }} cron job started" state=present
  when: inventory_hostname == item.s
  with_items:
  - { s: 'hosta', h: 1 }
  - { s: 'hostb', h: 2 }
  - { s: 'hostc', h: 3 }
```